# how can i get the "post id"(foreign key field connected with comment model) to the django comments form without post_detail page in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am creating a single page blog site how can i get the post id to the comments form , I created django forms with necessary field but the problem is ,I have to select the post id from a drop down menu manually while commenting, for that I passed  post object as an input value of a form to views.py file but django needs instance to save in database what should I do now
note :I am not using post_detail

**models.py**

```
class comments(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content=models.TextField()
    post=models.ForeignKey(blog,related_name="comments",on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    #blog is the model to which comment is related
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class commentform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=comments
        fields=('name','content','post')

        widgets={
            'name' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'type your name here'}),
            'content' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'post' : forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
        }
```

**Html**

```
<form method='POST' action="comment_action" class='form-group'>
{%csrf_token%}
{{form.name}}
{{form.content}}
<input type="text" id="objid" name="objid" value="{{objs.id}}" hidden>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm shadow-none"  type="submit">Post comment</button>
```

**views.py**

```
def comment_action(request):
    name=request.POST.get('name')
    content=request.POST.get('content')
    objid=request.POST.get('objid')
    to_db=comments.objects.create(name=name,content=content,post=objid)
    print(name,content,objid)
    return redirect('/homepage')
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

**ERROR :**

Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:
Cannot assign "'48'": "comments.post" must be a "blog" instance.

-->48 is my blog id

i know that database will only accept instance post field because that was a foreign key
my question is how to pass it  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign it with `post_id`:

```
def comment_action(request):
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    content = request.POST.get('content')
    objid = request.POST.get('objid')
    to_db = comments.objects.create(name=name, content=content, post_id=objid)
    print(name,content,objid)
    return redirect('/homepage')
```

---

> **Note**: It is better to use a [**`Form`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)
> than to perform manual validation and cleaning of the data. A `Form` will not
> only simplify *rendering* a form in HTML, but it also makes it more convenient
> to *validate* the input, and *clean* the data to a more convenient type.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Comment` instead of <s>`comments`</s>.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot bro you made my day,it worked